# Flutter save image after processing and return image instance

Tags: image, flutter, save, ocr

I need to preprocess images to feed to ml_kit stand alone to ocr.  My first challance was grayscale.  I use below grayscale method from Image.

```
img.Image grayscale(img.Image src) {
  final p = src.getBytes();
  for (var i = 0, len = p.length; i < len; i += 4) {
    final l = img.getLuminanceRgb(p[i], p[i + 1], p[i +         2]);
    p[i] = l;
    p[i + 1] = l;
    p[i + 2] = l;
  }
  return src;
}
```

i import Image like import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

I call the function like next after get it from image_picker and saving it to documents

```
      var image = img.decodeImage(savedImage!.readAsBytesSync())!;

    final grayImage = grayscale(image);
```

Now I need to get the path of the returned image and I do not find a way to do it.  Tried to save it but I can not find a path or   a way to get a path to the returned image to pass to the ocr function.  How do I save the 'instance of image' or get the path to it.  I do not want to display it just need to call it to the textreader function as a string for the path so it can be processed by the text reader function

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I red the docs again and found this and it looks like it works. File img2 = await File('${dir.path}/thumbnail.png').writeAsBytes(img.encodePng(img1));